# Solving problems recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion

Our professor gave us the following assignment:

> A "correct" series is one in which the sum of its members equals to the index of its first member.

The program is supposed to find the length of the LONGEST "correct" series within a series of n numbers.

For example: if the input series would be `arr[4]={1, 1, 0, 0}`
the output (longest "correct" series) would be `3`.
`arr[0]=1. 0!=1` therefore the longest series here is `0`.
`arr[1]=1,and 1=1.` but the following members also sum up to 1 as shown below:
`1=arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3] = 1+ 0 + 0`, therefore the longest series here is `3`.

The output in this example is `3`.

This is what I have so far:

```
int solve(int arr[], int index, int length,int sum_so_far)
{
     int maxwith,maxwithout;

     if(index==length)
         return 0;

     maxwith = 1+ solve(arr,index+1,length,sum_so_far+arr[index]);
     maxwithout = solve(arr,index+1,length,arr[index+1]);

     if(sum_so_far+arr[index]==index)
         if(maxwith>maxwithout) 
            return maxwith;

     return maxwithout;

     return 0;
}



int longestIndex(int arr[], int index,int length)
{
     return solve(arr,0,length,0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

We aren't supposed to us loops on this assignment.

Comment: "sum of its members equals to the index of its first member" - the index of it's first member is always 0.  I think you have a typo here.

Comment: I think he means the first member of the series, not the array. In his example, the series contains members 1, 2, and 3, so the first member's index is 1.

Comment: @Tim: don't think it's a typo, so what if it's 0? @Harry86: what isn't working? are you getting a wrong answer, an error or what?

Comment: This problem doesn't immediately strike me as being particulary suitbale for a recursive solution. I think your teacher should come up with better problems!

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: Why not? I think it’s a good example, and very amenable to a recursive solution.

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed in the array? This drastically impacts the algorithm.

Comment: @Konrad: because it can be solved in less lines, with greater clarity, and probably more efficiently, by a non-recursive solution. It just doesn't strike me as obviously recursive in the way that a fibonacci or other classic example does. Maybe that just means I'm a rubbish coder though :)

Comment: “it can be solved in less lines, with greater clarity, and probably more efficiently, by a non-recursive solution” – that’s a great claim, and very probably wrong. The problem can be solved most efficiently and most elegantly using dynamic programming, which is naturally modelled as recursion with memoization. In fact, that problem positively *cries* “dynamic programming”. And hence “recursion”.

Comment: Ok maybe so, I'll take your word for it. All I know is I solved it in about 10 lines with a couple of loops and a `GetLongest(array)` and a `GetLongestFromIndex(array, int)` method, it took me about 2 minutes and it worked first time. I just don't see any point in solving this recursively. Hats off to you if you see this and instantly see a recursive solution, but I hope I never have to debug any of your code :)

Comment: IVlad, all of his examples don't add up to 0, so it's unlikely that is what he meant

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, there are several problems with this program.

Most obvious, "return maxwithout; return 0;" should give a compile error: There's no way to get to that last return statement.

Second, you're recursing in to solve on the "maxwith" path until you reach the end of the array. Then you're going to recurse into maxwithout, hitting it for the first time with index=4. I don't think this is going to work.

Frankly, I don't think this problem really calls for recursion. THe most natural solution would be a nested loop:

```
for (int start=0;start<length;++start)
{
  for (int end=start;end<length;++end)
  {
    // calculate the sum of arr[start]->arr[end] and compare to start
  }
}
```

Or something to that effect.

Did the problem call for solving it with recursion, or was that just your first idea at a good solution?

**Edit**

Okay, so you have to use recursion. I guess the point of the lesson is to learn to use recursion, not necessarily to solve the problem in the most natural or efficient way. (Personally, I think the teacher should have come up with a problem where recursion was a natural solution, but I guess we're not here to critique the teacher today.)

I don't want to do your homework for you, but I'll give you a hint. You can use recursion to simulate a loop by putting the break condition at the beginning of the function and  putting the recursive call at the end of the function with a +1 parameter. That is, instead of writing

```
for (int x=0;x<10;++x) { ... whatever ...}
```

you can write

```
void forx(int x)
{
  if (x>=10)
    return;
  ... whatever ...
  forx(x+1);
}
```

So in this case I'd do something like:

```
void endloop(int start, int end)
{
  if (end>=arrayLength)
    return;
  ... work on running total ...
  endloop(start, end+1);
}

void startloop(int start)
{
  if (start>=arrayLength)
    return;
  endloop(start, start);
}
int main()
{
  ... setup ...
  startloop(0);
  ... output ...
}
```

Parameter lists are not necessarily complete. As I say, I don't want to do your homework for you, just give you a hint to get started.

Comment: it's my teacher that insists we don't use loops on this one...extremely annoying.

Comment: C won't give a compile error for dead code by default. (Only Java would).

Answer (score 2):

First, write a function that tests a series of given starting index and given length for the "sum of its members" condition. Then, write a second function which looks for the longest series within your array where only the starting index is given (looping over the sub-series length in decreasing order should do it); this function can call the first one. At last, write a third function looping over all starting indexes, calling function number two.

Oh wait, there is no recursion needed any more, so a lot of brain-twisting is gone ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem lies here:

```
if(sum_so_far+arr[index]==index)
```

You're comparing the sum so far with the current index, but you should be comparing it with the first index in the series. It seems to me that it would be better if you started with the last element of arr towards the first, instead of going in the natural order. That way you start summing elements up until the sum equals the current index.